# Can't save Keras model

Tags: python, keras, google-colaboratory

I'm using Colab to create a simple Keras model, compile it, train it, run predictions and then try to save the model as described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/g3doc/python_api.md#basic-keras-file)

The problem is that I get this error:

```
 FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value input/kernel
 [[Node: _retval_input/kernel_0_1 = _Retval[T=DT_FLOAT, index=1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](input/kernel)]]
```

Here is my model:

```
locModel = Sequential()
locModel.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(240, 130,1), name='input'))
locModel.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
locModel.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
locModel.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))     
locModel.add(Conv2D(128, (2, 2), activation='relu'))
locModel.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
locModel.add(Flatten())
locModel.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
locModel.add(Dense(8, name='predicted_corners'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
locModel.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer=sgd)
```

Training:

```
hist = locModel.fit(imageData, 
                localization_labels, 
                epochs=100, 
                validation_split=0.2,
               callbacks=[tbCallBack])
```

Evaluation:

```
predictions = locModel.predict(testImages)
```

Then I try to save it, as described in the link above:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K

KERAS_MODEL_NAME = "keras.hdf5"

# Save tf.keras model in HDF5 format.
tf.keras.models.save_model(locModel, KERAS_MODEL_NAME)
```

Any help appreciated!

TensorFlow version: **1.10.0**

Keras version: **2.1.6**

**Update 1:**

```
locModel.save_weights('weights.h5')
```

completes without errors - my ultimate goal is to convert to TFLite, so I need the whole graph.

**Update 2:**

Added initialisers for the layers:

```
locModel = Sequential()
locModel.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(240, 130,1), name='input', kernel_initializer='random_uniform'))
locModel.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
locModel.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_uniform'))
locModel.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))        
locModel.add(Conv2D(128, (2, 2), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_uniform'))
locModel.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
locModel.add(Flatten( ))
locModel.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
locModel.add(Dense(8, name='predicted_corners'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
locModel.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer=sgd)
```

after the above changes I get the following error

```
ValueError: Fetch argument <tf.Variable 'input_1/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 1, 32) dtype=float32_ref> cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Tensor Tensor("input_1/kernel:0", shape=(3, 3, 1, 32), dtype=float32_ref) is not an element of this graph.)
```

Comment: what keras/tf version are you using. The error is complaining that the first conv2d layer has no kernel initialization, you can probably fix it by adding `kernel_initalizer` as the param to all your conv layers.

Comment: @modesitt updated question to include versions. The model can train and evaluate, is the `kernerl_initializer` required only for saving/freezing ?

Comment: it should normally never be required, but that is what the error implies. This is definitely strange behavior. What happens when you just `save_weights` and not the full architecture.

Comment: `locModel.save_weights('model1_weights.h5')` completes without errors - my ultimate goal is to convert to TFLite, so I need the whole graph...

Comment: yeah this is definitly a bug from new TF deprecation stuff. Try adding a `kernel_initializer` to all your layers. just random normal and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: @modesitt added `kernel_initializer` to layers, re-trained and now I get the following error when trying to save `Fetch argument <tf.Variable 'input_1/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 1, 32) dtype=float32_ref> cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Tensor Tensor("input_1/kernel:0", shape=(3, 3, 1, 32), dtype=float32_ref) is not an element of this graph.)`

Comment: What if you do model.save("model.hdf5") ?

Answer (score 0):

Change from:

```
tf.keras.models.save_model(locModel, KERAS_MODEL_NAME)
```

into just:

```
keras.models.save_model(locModel, KERAS_MODEL_NAME)
```

You are mixing tensorflow.keras with keras packages which you use to create your model which doesn't seem to be allowed.  Make sure to restart your notebook to clean out the old inconsistencies within the model.  I was having the exact same problem and once I consistently used the same packages for all keras calls it worked.